# Extracting value from jmeter response data

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to extract a particular value from the Response data

Below is the Response data:

```
{"results": [{"Withdrawn": false,"WorkflowID": 1169,"Subject": "@@@Legal Hold Testing@@@ Tue, 30 Aug 2016","DueDate": new Date(1472083200000),"SCUserID": 29625,"AdminEmail": "puventhira-mannen-pragasam.selladurai@hpe.com?subject=Ask%20a%20Question%20-%20@@@Legal%20Hold%20Testing@@@%20Tue,%2030%20Aug%202016","CC": false,"TypeIconURL": "/resources/images/icon_notification.gif","eventLink": "https://c9w24074.itcs.hpecorp.net/lfserver?DFS__Action=RouteGetForm&DFS__DataSource=1&DFS__TargetWindow=45361a9d438b352de521f444_476622041&DFS__EventID=45361a9d438b352de521f444_476622041&**DFS__SessionID=2x7635cd045f99c79z156c847a5eezx4094guxbpsxohxgoh**","EventID": "45361a9d438b352de521f444_476622041","WorkflowType": "Notice"}
```

I want `DFS__SessionID=[value]`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter).

Here is your **Regular Expression** for DFS__SessionID=[value]:

```
DFS__SessionID=(\w*)
```

You can test this expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/iK8vK0/1).

Answer (score -1):

Use regular exp like this mentioned in the image and use the variable ${sessionid} to get the dynamic value

[Regular exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT9eV.png)